# Playing music with pyspotify, what am I missing?

Tags: python, spotify

Im new to Python and I am trying to make a class where I will play some music with the spotify library pyspotify. I have the code below and I taught that it would be playing music if I run the play method. This does not work because I can't hear any music playing, no error messages appear from what I can see. What do I have to do more?

```
import spotify
import threading

class Music:
    session = None

    def __init__(self):
        logged_in_event = threading.Event()

        def connection_state_listener(session):
            if session.connection.state is spotify.ConnectionState.LOGGED_IN:
                logged_in_event.set()

        self.session = spotify.Session()
        loop = spotify.EventLoop(self.session)
        loop.start()
        self.session.on(
                   spotify.SessionEvent.CONNECTION_STATE_UPDATED,
                   connection_state_listener)

        self.session.login('accountname', 'password')
        logged_in_event.wait()

        print self.session.connection.state
        print self.session.user

    def play(self):
        track = self.session.get_track('spotify:track:2Foc5Q5nqNiosCNqttzHof')
        track.load()

        self.session.player.load(track)
        self.session.player.play(play=True)
```

And in another Python file I do:

```
music = Music.Music()
music.play()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "seems not to work"? Can you describe what happens, in as much detail as possible? If you get an error message, post the whole thing.

Comment: I edited my post above!

Comment: Do you have Spotify Premium and an application key?

Comment: Yes I have! I have the application key in the same folder as the code above.

Comment: Does execution reach the `print` lines?

Comment: yes, it does reach that

Answer (score 1):

I added the line

```
audio = spotify.AlsaSink(session)
```

and now it works!

Comment: For other readers, this is documented at http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/quickstart/#playing-music